# How to parse GPS data sent in NMEA protocol by multiple devices?

Tags: node.js, parsing, geolocation, gps, nmea

We are building a real-time bus tracking system for a client. The buses send GPS data to the configured server in NMEA 0183 protocol.

We tested the configuration on one bus. Our NMEA parser on our server is able to decode the sentences and give us the latitude longitude of the bus location.

But we are unable to verify that the data is coming from that bus itself. So, how will we detect and parse data sent by multiple buses?

Comment: By bus, do you mean like a transit bus that people ride on, or the electrical RS-485 bus used for NMEA communication?

Answer (score 0):

> The buses send GPS data to the configured server in NMEA 0183 protocol.

The NMEA protocol is very wordy and contains duplicated fields in different sentences.  It would be **much** more efficient to parse the NMEA sentences in the bus.  Then you can send a "message" to the server that contains the parsed values and a bus ID:  latitude, longitude, date/time, speed and bus ID.  This message is **10 to 80 times smaller** than the raw NMEA data.  The records in the server can then be used to display bus locations.

If you are using an Arduino microcontroller to connect to a GPS module, you should take a look at my NMEA parsing library, [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  It is supported on all the Arduino platforms.